# Jenkins Build Failure:Getting java.lang.NullPointerException at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$PomParser.<init>(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:1171)

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

I'm facing this issue with Jenkins when trying to build the maven project.

I checked few suggestions but none of them seem to answer my problem.

Error log is attached below. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
ERROR: Processing failed due to a bug in the code. Please report this to the issue tracker (https://jenkins.io/redirect/report-an-issue).
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.Hashtable.put(Hashtable.java:460)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$PomParser.<init>(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:1171)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.parsePoms(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:985)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.doRun(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:689)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:516)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1889)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:543)
```

I checked my maven and java version. I am using maven 3.5.4 and java 1.8 versions. I expected to run the build successfully, But got the same error again.

Comment: What does your maven project look like?  There's something in your project that Maven doesn't seem to like.

Comment: Which Jenkins version do you use? How have you configured Maven and your build to be run? Second Why do you use such an old version of Maven?

Comment: I am using Jenkins 2.303.1 version. Yes, configured maven. In my project they are using this old version of maven.

Comment: How have you configured Maven? Using global tools configuration? Or how?

Comment: yeah yes, in global tool configuration only

Comment: Hi @Bhavitha. How did you get your issue solved, finally ? Thanks